# Java Junit failing when expected and actual are the same?

Tags: java, junit

I have finished developing a big project I have been working on. I have usually done my own tests without Junit but my requirement is to use it now. All of my methods that I want to test are void and do not return anything, but print information depending on certain factors. So, I need to test these using the `assertEquals` method for Junit.

For example:

```
public void addContact(String firstName,String lastName,Person p) {
       String key = firstName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + firstName.substring(1).toLowerCase() + " ".concat(lastName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + lastName.substring(1).toLowerCase());
    if(hasContact(key)){
        System.out.println("\nCannot add user. User already exists. Try adding distinct name to diffentiate between users with the same name");
    }
    else{
       this.contacts.put(key,p);
       System.out.println("\nUser: " + key + " Successfully added");
    }
    }
```

This is one of the void methods I want to test from my AddressBook class, for now, I am testing to see if the user can be added so it should print `\nUser: " + key + " Successfully added` which it does.

Here in my JUNIT test class, I am trying to check this like so...

```
@Test
    public void addContact(){
         final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();



         Address a1 = new Address("grove","Waterford","Waterford","x9123r","0987654321");
        Person p1 = new Person("Charlie","Ansell",a1);
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
        ad1.addContact("Charlie","Ansell", p1);
        assertEquals("User: Charlie Ansell Successfully added", outContent.toString());


    }
```

The output from Junit is: `expected:<[User: Charlie Ansell Successfully added]> but was <[User: Charlie Ansell Successfully added]>`

My question is, why is this failing if they are showing the same output?

Comment: Just because they look the same doesn't mean they are actually the same. Some characters look like other characters. Some characters are invisible.

Answer (score 2):

Despite content looks similar you have extra line breaks (`\n`) in your program that your did not include in your test.

Replace:

> assertEquals("User: Charlie Ansell Successfully added", outContent.toString());

with:

> assertEquals("\nUser: Charlie Ansell Successfully added\n", outContent.toString());

Comment: Yeah, you also miss line break at the end. Test passes for me

Comment: did the test pass for you without using ``.trim``I just posted an answer, I had to trim both objects to pass the test

Answer (score 2):

have you tried debugging it and looking at the difference?
My guess - missing `\n` both at the beginning (from your code) and the end (you are using `println`).

this should work:
        assertEquals("\nUser: Charlie Ansell Successfully added\n", outContent.toString());

Comment: Hi, Nir. Unfortunately, that failed also, I have debugged it and it looks the same

Comment: 'looks' doesn't say much. what's the result of `equals()`? what's the result of `trim().equals()`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have just discovered the answer.

I added the `.trim()` function at the end of the expected object and actual object. so my new code looks like this:

```
@Test
public void addContact(){
     final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();



     Address a1 = new Address("grove","Waterford","Waterford","x9123r","0987654321");
    Person p1 = new Person("Charlie","Ansell",a1);
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
    ad1.addContact("Charlie","Ansell", p1);
    assertEquals("\nUser: Charlie Ansell Successfully added\n".trim(), outContent.toString().trim());


}
```

My assumption from this is that there were blank spaces in both of the outputs, thanks to all who commented, I appreciate the help